# Malloc replacement by user

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, malloc, allocation

I want to ask you for help with my own project.
I want to try to replace original malloc, free functions by my own functions which will have same behavior.

```
int memory_free(void *ptr){}
void memory_init(void *ptr, unsigned int size){}
void *memory_alloc(unsigned int size){}
```

The memory_init function will create a memory to work with. At the beggining there will be pointer for example *Memory and it will be the argument for memory_init. Memory init will be called only once at the beginning of the program.

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char region[50];
  memory_init(region, 50);
  char* pointer = (char*) memory_alloc(10); 
  if (pointer)
  memset(pointer, 0, 10);
  if (pointer)
  memory_free(pointer);
  return 0;
}
```

this code is the example of testing my functions. Memory_init will initialize memory and memory_alloc will create blocks in this memory for every call.
If there is someone who have idea how to make it i will be glad to see your answer.
Sorry for my english.
thx.

for memory_init i have this

```
*Memory;
 void memory_init(void *ptr, unsigned int size){
 *((unsigned int*)ptr)=size; //at first position there will be size of whole memory;

}
```

My idea is to make one block of memory and in it there will be small block. every block will have head. at first position there will be size of block and after it there will be tag if it is free or not and after it there will be end of the block.

Answer (score 2):

Section 8.7 of the classic Kernighan&Ritchie "The C Programming Language" describes exactly what you are asking in simple terms.  You can find copies of it on the web in various places.  You can also find more sophisticated malloc implementations [here](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) or [here](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/shm_malloc)

Answer (score 0):

malloc() uses the sbrk system call to request more memory. Afaik it is the only way to do it.